"Our true enemy has yet to reveal himself." Intentional misquote?
In Season 2, Episode 13, of The Sopranos, Tony has a dream in which he meets Silvio Dante, who says

Our true enemy has yet to reveal himself.

Obviously, this is supposed to be a quote from the movie The Godfather Part III, considering Silvio has previously done impressions of Michael Corleone and, in this dream, is dressed like Michael Corleone in The Godfather Part III.
However, in the scene that is being quoted, Michael Corleone actually says

Our true enemy has not yet shown his face.

Has there ever been information on whether or not the misquoting of the scene has been intentional or a mistake? If it was intentional, what is the meaning behind the change?

Tony frequently misquotes things
